# Passing dataframe rows to addRow function in Google Charts

Tags: python, flask, charts, google-visualization

**My main aim is to pass the row values in the [google line chart which is supposed to be in this format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)**

```
data.addRows([
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2]
]);
```

**Data -**  (dataframe)

```
+----------------+--------+---------+
| day_month_year | Sender | Message |
+----------------+--------+---------+
| 2015-12-01     | Bob    |      41 |
| 2015-12-01     | Jane   |      55 |
| 2015-12-02     | Bob    |      96 |
| 2015-12-02     | Jane   |     132 |
| 2015-12-03     | Bob    |      52 |
+----------------+--------+---------+
```

**`data2.values` returns -**

```
array([[Timestamp('2015-12-01 00:00:00'), 'Bob', 41],
       [Timestamp('2015-12-01 00:00:00'), 'Jane', 55],
       [Timestamp('2015-12-02 00:00:00'), 'Bob', 96],
       ...,
       [Timestamp('2019-07-31 00:00:00'), 'Jane', 18],
       [Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Bob', 2],
       [Timestamp('2019-08-02 00:00:00'), 'Bob', 1]], dtype=object)
```

**Now my code runs well in flask but when see the source code, it is returning below value**

```
      data.addRows([[Timestamp(&#39;2018-11-09 00:00:00&#39;) &#39;Bob&#39; 68]
 [Timestamp(&#39;2018-11-09 00:00:00&#39;) &#39;Jane&#39; 86]
 [Timestamp(&#39;2018-11-10 00:00:00&#39;) &#39;Bob&#39; 40]
 ...
 [Timestamp(&#39;2019-06-15 00:00:00&#39;) &#39;Bob&#39; 20]
 [Timestamp(&#39;2019-06-15 00:00:00&#39;) &#39;Jane&#39; 21]
 [Timestamp(&#39;2019-06-16 00:00:00&#39;) &#39;Bob&#39; 1]]);
```

**My flask code -**

```
 return render_template("viz.html", data=data2, cols=col_names)
```

**Google Chart code to populate rows -**

```
data.addRows({{ data.values  }});
```

**Question -**

1. How do I get rid of the `Timestamp('` and `00:00:00)`
2. How do I remove `&#39`?
3. Is there a better way to pass dataframe values in format of

   [['value 1','value 2', value 3],
    ['value 4','value 5', value 6]....]
4. How do I add `'` around my values?

Comment: try adding `| safe` here --> `{{ data.values  | safe }}`